# Javascript Not Calling PHP function in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to get the following code to work:

//In Javascript

```
function updateContentEditable(){

var span = $(this);
var data = new Object();

data.pid = '1';

data.content = 'this is a test';

data.action = 'update_content'; //This should run update_content php function

$.post(ajaxPath, data, onContentSaved); //ajaxPath returns: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
}
```

//In PHP

```
function update_content(){

echo "<script>alert (\"php was reached\")</script>";

}
```

NOTE:

//onContentSaved is this:

function onContentSaved(data){
   console.log(data);
}

My problem is the the php function is not being run.

What I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: I suggest that you remove the PHP function and just `echo` directly, or include a PHP condition that calls the function depending on posted data. Passing "data.action" will not automatically call a function in the PHP page.

Comment: Have you properly defined the action callback like in [this tutorial](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)?

Comment: Tried this: $.post(ajaxPath, data, function(response) {
alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
}); but got no return at all

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using jquery, try this:

```
function SendRequestCallBack(webMethod, parameters, callBack) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: webMethod,
        data: parameters,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(results) {
            $(".ajaxImage").hide();
             eval(callBack(results.d));
        }
    });
}

function formatData(obj){
    alert(obj);
}
$(document).ready(function()
{
    SendRequestCallBack("http://url-to-php","{'any':'parameters'}",formatData);
});
```

Then all the PHP needs to do is echo valid JSON.  Or if you like you can change the `contentType:` parameter to text/xml or text/plain etc depending on what you want it to return.  Keep in mind that your PHP needs to output the matching content type as well.  for example 
    `<?php
    header("Content-type: text/json");
    echo {"d":[{"firstname":"John","lastname":"Doe"},{"firstname":"Jane","lastname":"Doe"}]}
    ?>`

If you want to pass data in to the PHP function, set it in the parameters, and make sure that your PHP will accommodate it using the $_POST array.